# Desfire EV1 Communication - How to assign IV

Tags: encryption, aes, nfc, apdu, mifare

AES-128 authentication process with Desfire EV1 cards goes like this:

- Get Application IDs: **90 6A 00 00 00**
- Select Application: **90 5A 00 00 03 10 00 00 00** (AID: 0x000010)
- Start Authentication with a key: **90 AA 00 00 01 02 00** (Key: 0x02)
- Card responses with a random 16 bytes array, lets call that **RANDOM_B**
- Now card needs more data to continue authentication, so we will do that
- Decrypt **RANDOM_B** with ***KEY*** and ***an empty IV***, lets call that **RANDOM_B_DEC**
- Left shift 1 byte **RANDOM_B_DEC**, lets call that **RANDOM_B_DEC_LS**
- Create a 16 bytes long random array, lets call that **RANDOM_A**
- Combine **RANDOM_A** and **RANDOM_B_DEC_LS** into a single 32 bytes array, lets call that **ARRAY**
- Encrypt this **ARRAY** using ***KEY*** and ***RANDOM_B as IV***, lets call that **ARRAY_ENC**
- Send **ARRAY_ENC** to continue authentication process: **90 AF 00 00 20 + *ARRAY_ENC* + 00**
- Now card responses with 16 bytes shifted and encrypted **RANDOM_A** and we need to decrypt and compare this with our own **RANDOM_A** that we created earlier

Here is my question: While decrypting received RANDOM_A (last step) what IV array I must use?

After that, how can I read data from a file in selected and authenticated application? Is this data also received encrypted? If yes, what will I use as IV array for decryption?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to have a look [here](https://github.com/nfc-tools/libfreefare/blob/c18f7028406e3de2938cbab070539f6d6c031baf/libfreefare/mifare_desfire.c#L351) (in C) and [here](https://github.com/Andrade/nfcjlib/blob/06056c4ca340164ebbeee790c0ef061e0b2a3d86/src/nfcjlib/core/DESFireEV1.java#L89) (in java).

Comment: @vlp Thank you very much. I figured out from the java code and my program works!!